# Find used types and members from a specific assembly

Tags: ndepend

I am trying to create a CQLinq query which will give me all types and/or members from a specific assembly that is being used by the rest of the solution.

I need this information so I can move/refactor all the referenced types/members and in the end remove the specific assembly (and all references to it) from the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For optimal result presentation, the query can look like:

```
let targets = Assemblies.WithName("SpecificAssemblyName").Single().ChildTypesAndMembers.ToHashSet()

let methodsUser = Application.Methods.UsingAny(targets)
let typesUser = Application.Types.UsingAny(targets)
from x in ((IEnumerable<IMember>)typesUser).Concat(methodsUser)
where !targets.Contains(x)

select new { 
   x, 
   called = x.IsMethod ? x.AsMethod.MethodsCalled.Intersect(targets).Concat(x.AsMethod.FieldsUsed.Intersect(targets)) :
   x.AsType.TypesUsed.Intersect(targets)}
```

[image]